# Android video streaming not valid on some device

Tags: android

I use a VideoView to display on the device a mp4 video file. It work very well on all device but on other such as : galaxy next, LG P500 it display this message "the video is not valid for streaming on this device ?"

Why ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wether an android device can show the video depends on which video-codecs the device manufacturer has compiled in.

You can ask the [CamcorderProfile api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html) if your device supports the requested video format.

The [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) show you wich codecs should be supported .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MP4 is encoded with the H.264 baseline profile. Make sure it is being served up with an HTTP 1.1 response. And also run it through MP4Box. We had numerous device-specific playback issues and doing all of the above has resolved them.

This post may also be helpful: [Cannot play certain videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728085/cannot-play-certain-videos)